# django second project on the same server: Settings file logic not evaluating properly?

Tags: linux, django

I have a server running two django projects and I have made an environment variable on my server and I check to see if it is there before running some logic in the settings which will choose whether debug is on or off... This works perfectly in my first project but I just implemented it in my second and there are a few problems...

```
if 'PRODUCTION_SERVER' in os.environ:
    REAL = True
else:
    REAL = False

if REAL:
    DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['mydomain.com',]
else:
    # SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
    DEBUG = True
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
```

1. The setting of the REAL variable is evaluating to `False` and I have already checked that it is in my server environment, both from an ssh shell and the django shell. Why would that be?

EDIT, I exported the variable in /etc/bash.bashrc...

```
export PRODUCTION=True
```

and when I look at printenv I see that it is there...

Comment: Is this project in a virtual env? how do you set the variable?

Comment: the project is in a virtualenv...The variable is exported through some file on the system, I will try and find it and add it to the post when I do...

Comment: @Sayse, added to post

Comment: Setting the variable in your .bashrc is a weird way to do it, and means only things _your user_ runs _from bash_ will see that variable. Whether Django sees that depends how you run your project. If you're using supervisor to run your project, it won't work. You can look at the environment of a running process with `$ cat /proc/$pid/environ` to check what's going on.

Comment: Im not using supervisor. Weird thing is that my other project see it and it runs under the same user...either case what would be the proper way to do this? I made this solution oit of necessity...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to find out what my problem was, I ended up realizing that I had different BASE_DIR settings for the different servers, so I wrote an if statement based on that to differentiate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

make both variables as either `PRODUCTION` or `PRODUCTION_SERVER`. Also, if I may add, don't default to debug = True, since you will need different settings for testing, development, staging etc. You can have a base.py in settings folder and inherit that file with DEBUG=true/false in your respective dev.py/prod.py

Comment: That was my mistake in typingon this site. THat is not the problem here

Comment: the way to do it in virtual enviroment would be to put the variable in postactivate file